# Is it safe to upload my .crk and .pem file for my open source chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Would it be safe if I uploaded the .crx and .pem files for an open-source chrome application? What could someone do if they had both of the files? I assume the files aren't needed anyway if you have the unpacked extension (as I understand it, the .crx file is the extension itself), so would uploading the files to GitHub give someone the opportunity to do someone malicious (should I gitignore the files), or would it be a safe way to back up these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pem file for Google Chrome extensions are private keys and should not be distributed. The only way you would have gotten a pem file is by packaging up the extension on your own device. While you can do this the usefulness is limited as most users won't be able to install extensions via file instead of through the Chrome Web Store.

The private key is used to guarantee that future updates are from the same source as the original extension install. Anyone who has the private key can package extensions that Chrome users think were developed and deployed by you.

Note: if you have a Chrome extension pem file and have not yet published the extension to the Chrome Web Store, that anyone with the private key can create a listing of the extension and all existing users will automatically update to the CWS version.

Answer (score 2):

A .pem file is just a shell for the real certificate. The only problem is that it can have a variety of different payloads like a private key of just a public certificate or even whole certificate chains. If the pem file you have is only a public certificate you can distribute it. If it has a private key then under no circumstance should you give it to anyone because they can impersonate you. You can check what the pem file has in it with the portecle application. A quick google search will bring you to the application home page.

Comment: Thanks! If I didn't enter a private key to be used, what implications would that have for me if I distributed it? I thought they'd need to have access to the chrome dev account I used to upload it in order to impersonate me though?

Comment: If there is no private key in the file then you can distribute it, no implications. You can be impersonated in different ways for instance if your extension uses TLS/SSL for networking then you can get a man in the middle attack.

Comment: In the context of Google extensions, the PEM file is the **private** key. If a third party had your PEM key, they could issue updates for the extension.